# How to fix "Failed building wheel for pyscipopt"?

Tags: python, anaconda, scip

I'm trying to install Pyscipopt for homework. There was an installation guide on the school website, the problem is that it doesn't work on my laptop. I have to write "pip install pyscipopt" in Anaconda Prompt, but I get the error "failed building wheel for pyscipopt". I don't know what it means or how to solve this, can anyone help me?

```
(base) C:\Users\claire>pip install pyscipopt
Collecting pyscipopt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/47/e3d5fcc37138c0eb9695d7c26e22b999c1274b06606db183c2aa36f98e5a/PySCIPOpt-2.2.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
  Building wheel for pyscipopt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\claire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zja79xrm\\pyscipopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jnmor4q4' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Using include path <C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\src>.
  Using SCIP library <scip> at <C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\lib>.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pyscipopt
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\src -IC:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
  scip.c
  src\pyscipopt\scip.c(621): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'scip/scip.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
  Running setup.py clean for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
Installing collected packages: pyscipopt
  Running setup.py install for pyscipopt ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\claire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zja79xrm\\pyscipopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aw3wx8lo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Using include path <C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\src>.
    Using SCIP library <scip> at <C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\lib>.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pyscipopt
    running build_ext
    building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pyscipopt
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\src -IC:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
    scip.c
    src\pyscipopt\scip.c(621): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'scip/scip.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\claire\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\claire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zja79xrm\\pyscipopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aw3wx8lo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\claire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zja79xrm\pyscipopt\
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message that you got. Also, please verify that you follow these instructions: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 6):

This is the actual error:

```
 Cannot open include file: 'scip/scip.h': No such file or directory
```

To resolve it, please carry out the installation instructions as outlined [here](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md). Most importantly, you need to install the SCIP Optimization Suite first. You can get the Windows installer [here](https://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=SCIPOptSuite-6.0.2-win64-VS15.exe). After installing, you need to set an environment variable telling the PySCIPOpt installer where to find the SCIP library for linking:

```
 set SCIPOPTDIR="C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite-6.0.2"
 pip install pyscipopt
```

(assuming you used the default installation path for the SCIPOptSuite)

Comment: Thank you! I have already installed the SCIP Optimization Suite. I have read the instructions, but I don't know what to do, because I don't understand. I don't know where to type "set SCIPOPTDIR=<path_to_install_dir>" and what path I have to write. And how do I set an environment variable telling the PySCIPOpt installer where to find the SCIP library for linking? This may be dumb questions, but I am really bad at this, I just have to install it for my homework.

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to define the env variable in the same console/shell/command-line that you also use to run `pip install`.

Comment: Thank you, I installed SCIPOptSuite again and set an environment variable telling the PySCIPOpt installer where to find the SCIP library for linking, but I get the same error...

Comment: Can you confirm that the directories `SCIPOPTDIR\include` and `SCIPOPTDIR\lib` exist and that there is a `scip/scip.h` file in the one and some libraries in the other? The installation routine even prints which directory was used (`Using SCIP library <scip> at ...`). Please check that this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to install python conda:

```
pip install conda
```

The error displayed was:

```
Building wheel for pycosat (setup.py) ... error
...
pycosat.c:10:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory 10 |
#include <Python.h>`
```

The solution was to install python3-dev, which has the required header.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

The solution was here:
https://github.com/conda/pycosat/issues/34

It doesn't solve OP's specific problem, but I ended up here looking for a solution to this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyproject-toml
```

For building packages using this interface, pip uses an isolated environment. That is, pip will install build-time Python dependencies in a temporary directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
`pip install <package> --no-cache-dir`

Comment: `pip3 install wheel` or try updating the wheel